# $\dim (T^{-1}(X))$ when $T:V\mapsto W$ and $X$ is a subspace of $W$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Suppose $V$ and $W$ are two finite-dimensional vector spaces and $X$ is a subspace of $W$. If $T:V \mapsto W$ is a linear transformation, show that:
$$\dim (T^{-1}(X))\geq \dim(V)-\dim(W)+\dim(X).$$
where for any $S\subseteq W$ we set $T^{-1}(S) = \{v \in V: T(v)\in S\}$, thus $T^{-1}(X)$ is the set of vectors in $V$ that $T$ maps to $X$.

For example if $X=\{0\}$, then $T^{-1}(X)$ is the kernel of $T$ and the statement above holds. How can I show it for the general case?

Any help is immensely valuable to me!

Comment: I've tidied up your question a bit and clarified the definition of the preimage $T^{-1}(X)$.

Answer (score 2):

You say:

> I think $T^{-1}(X)$ should mean the image of $T^{-1}$ on $X$ (vectors from $V$ that $T$ maps them to $X$)

I will point out that the first part of this statement is badly phrased because $T$ may not be invertible. The thing that you wrote in the brackets makes sense (with minor modifications). Anyways, let's re-phrase the problem a little bit. You want to show that:
$$\dim(T^{-1}(X)) \geq \dim(V) - \dim(W)+\dim(X)$$

This is equivalent to showing that:
$$\dim(W) - \dim(X) \geq \dim(V) -\dim(T^{-1}(X))$$

which is equivalent to showing that:

$$\dim(W/X) \geq \dim(V/T^{-1}(X))$$

These are quotient vector spaces. This inequality can be proved by finding an injective linear map $S: V/T^{-1}(X) \to W/X$ as follows:
$$S: V/T^{-1}(X) \to W/X \ , \  v+ T^{-1}(X) \mapsto S(v+T^{-1}(X)) := T(v)+X$$

Showing that this is well-defined is fairly easy so I'll let you do that (but ask for help if you need it). Let's show that this is injective. Let:
$$S(v+T^{-1}(X)) = X$$

This implies that $T(v)+X = X$ so $T(v) \in X$. It follows that $v \in T^{-1}(X)$. But this means that $v+T^{-1}(X) = T^{-1}(X)$ and this proves that $S$ has trivial kernel so we're done. In the proof above, I've made use of the following result.

> If $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space and $U \subseteq V$ is a subspace, then $V/U$ is finite-dimensional and $\dim(V/U) = \dim(V)- \dim(U)$.

Comment: I highly appreciate your answer. But as this question is one of my howeworks, I should use concepts we're taught in the class. We're studying _Hoffman_ and _Kunze_ book and we've studied until chapter 3.5. So we don't know quotient vector spaces. But if you tell me an elementary definition (or a source so I can read) and a proof to $\dim(V/U)=\dim(V)-\dim(U)$ I can use it. Also if you know another proof that doesn't use quotient spaces, I would be thankful if you add it.

Comment: Have a look at Sterling Berberian's book on Linear Algebra. Specifically, have a look at Chapter 2.6 as well as Chapter 3.6; Theorem 3.6.1 is precisely the result which I used in the proof above. I'll try to come up with another argument which doesn't use quotient spaces.

Answer (score 2):

The reasoning here requires only the notion of basis.

Let's rewrite our inequality as follows
$$
\dim W-\dim X\geq\dim V-\dim Y,
$$
where $Y=T^{-1}(X)$.
Let $e_1,\ldots,e_s$ be the basis of $Y$ and $e_1,\ldots,e_s,e_{s+1},\ldots,e_n$ the basis of $V$.
We check that $T(e_{s+1}),\ldots,T(e_n)$ have the following property:
If
$$
\sum \alpha_iT(e_{s+i})\in X,
$$
then $\alpha_i=0$ for all $i$. (In particular, they are linearly independent.)
Therefore, if $x_1,\ldots,x_r$ is the basis of $X$, then $T(e_{s+1}),\ldots,T(e_n),x_1,\ldots,x_r$ is a linearly independent system in $W$.

But then $\dim W-\dim X\geq n-s$.
On the other hand, $\dim V-\dim Y=n-s$. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

The proof can be found in **Problem 7.4.3** of *Berkeley Problems in Mathematics*, third edition, by Paulo Ney de Souza and Jorge-Nuno Silva. Here, I will try to do a more detailed proof with minor changes.

Since $\text{range} \, T$ is a subspace of $W$, we know that $\dim(\text{range} \, T)\leq\dim (W)$. Therefore,

$$\dim(V)-\dim(\text{range} \, T)\geq\dim(V)-\dim (W).$$

Due to the fundamental theorem of linear maps, we know that $\dim(V)=\dim(\ker T)+\dim(\text{range} \, T)$. Therefore,

$$\dim(\ker T)\geq\dim(V)-\dim (W).$$

As you already have pointed out, $\ker T=T^{-1}(\{0\})$. Therefore,

$$\dim\left(T^{-1}(\{0\})\right)\geq\dim(V)-\dim (W). \ \ \ \ \ (1)$$

Since $T^{-1}(X)$ is the set of vectors in $V$ that $T$ maps to $X$, then restriction of $T$ to $T^{-1}(X)$ is the map $\left.T\right|_{T^{-1}(X)}:T^{-1}(X)\to X$. Applying the fundamental theorem of linear maps to $\left.T\right|_{T^{-1}(X)}$, we have

$$\dim(T^{-1}(X))=\dim(\ker \left.T\right|_{T^{-1}(X)})+\dim(\text{range} \, \left.T\right|_{T^{-1}(X)}).$$

By construction $\ker \left.T\right|_{T^{-1}(X)}=T^{-1}(\{0\})$ and $\text{range} \, \left.T\right|_{T^{-1}(X)}=X$. Therefore,

$$\dim(T^{-1}(X))=\dim(T^{-1}(\{0\}))+\dim(X)\Rightarrow\dim(T^{-1}(\{0\}))=\dim(T^{-1}(X))-\dim(X). \ \ \ \ \ (2)$$

Finally, substituting Eq. (2) into Eq. (1), we obtain the result
$$\dim(T^{-1}(X))\geq\dim(V)-\dim (W)+\dim(X).$$